# Why such a bizarre placement of 关于 in 请问关于解释《里》和《内》的区别?

Tags: word-choice, word-order

I came across this: 请问关于解释《里》和《内》的区别.

I have googled and "请问关于解释" happens on the Internet. However, according to what I have read [here](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/%E5%85%B3%E4%BA%8E), it's always placed after the verb. Is 解释 not a verb here? Why such a bizarre word order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 请问解释关于《里》和《内》的区别 (would you please tell/answer me about explaining the difference between《里》and《内》)

This sentence is awkward because 请问 (would you please tell me) is a set phrase that should followed by a question instead of a demand/ request "解释关于" (explain about).

The better phrasing would be:

1. **请解释**关于 **《里》和《内》的区别** (Please explain about the difference between 《里》and《内》)

   *关于(about) can be omitted*

or

2. **请问《里》和《内》有什麼区别?** (would you please tell/ answer me what is the difference between 《里》and《内》?)

> 请问关于解释《里》和《内》的区别 (would you please tell/ answer me about explaining the difference between《里》and《内》)

Even worse! Not only 请问 is followed by a demand/ request '解释' instead of a question, the order of 关于 and 解释 is also wrong. It is not "关于解释" (about explain) but  "解释关于" (explain about)

"请问关于解释《里》和《内》的区别" is just a badly constructed sentence.

Comment: 谢谢你的回答！So I was right something was off. Maybe I just copied the sentence wrong back when…

Answer (score 0):

"请问关于解释《里》和《内》的区别" is invalid sentence, we may say"请问《里》和《内》的区别",this is what the invalid sentence intends to express.
Also,"请问关于《里》和《内》的区别" is not good, or I may say it is an invalid sentence. 关于/《里》和《内》的//区别, or 关于//《里》和《内》的/区别 are all invalid.So 请解释关于 《里》和《内》的区别 is not proper sentence.

Comment: Are you saying that the last sentence you mentioned–the one Tang Ho has give as the correct one–is in fact not correct?

Comment: Right, he last sentence you mentioned–the one Tang Ho has give as the correct one–is in fact not correct.